# pandas clickable links not working after download

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I am trying to populate an xls sheet with clickable links. When I do `df.head()` it shows me clickable links but when I export `df` as excel, these links are not clickable anymore.

```
def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)

df = pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'])
df.style.format(make_clickable)
df.to_excel("j.xls")
```

How can I resolve such issues? Or pandas does not support clickable links after download?

Answer (score 0):

Use the extension `.xlsx` instead of `.xls` since this will be depreciated in the future.

And you should set the line `df.style.format(make_clickable)` to `df` else Python will be exporting the "non-clickable" dataframe to Excel.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(['http://google.com', 'http://duckduckgo.com'])

def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val,val)

df = df.style.format(make_clickable)
df.to_excel('j.xlsx')
```